# Determining the order/rank of my input when compared to a list of other numeric values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Sorry for the wall of words but this is the only way i can explain this.

background.  We are testing a product to see what levels of chemicals are in said product.  and depending on the chemical concentration we would either take no action, small action, or large actions.

So let's say Benzene.  if it's greater than or equal to 10 ppm then we need a large action, but if less than 10 ppm but greater or equal to 6 ppm then small action.  if it's less than 6 ppm but greater or equal to 3 ppm then no action but we will need to note it.  and below 3 ppm is do nothing.

So if my sample had 5ppm then i would need to take no action but i'd note it.
if my sample was 12ppm then i'd have to take action.

Maybe i'm think about this the wrong way but the easiest thing would be to some how rank my input against the tiers.  So 5ppm would yield a 2 because it's the 2nd smallest and then i can deduce that it's large enough that i have to note it but not large enough that i have to take action.

I'm sorry if it's still unclear.  new to this so please let me know how i can ask a better question

Comment: I understand that an input of `5` requires No action.  ...but how do get that the formula would return `2`? "...it's the 2nd smallest number.", of what? In general? (like how 1 is the smallest, 2 is second smallest, etc.)?  Can you please clarify what you're trying to do/return, and what have you tried so far? I'd think a relatively simply `If()` statement using `>=` type operators would work, no?

Comment: A `LOOKUP` can get you 2 from a 5 and anything else you want but I have no idea where the borders lie. As @BruceWayne states, what is a 2; what is a 1? For that matter, what is an 11?

Comment: @Jeeped ...Well, it’s one louder, innit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know OP's question should be clarified and refined. Maybe OP will do that. Anyway this will be helpful. When `A1:A3` is `{No action; small action; large action}` and `B1:B3` is `{3; 6; 10}`, and 'my value' `5` is on `D1`. Below array formula will give matched 'action'. Of course it's not working for a value which is larger than 10.

```
{=INDEX(A1:A3, MATCH(FALSE, B1:B3<$D$1, 0) - 1)}
```

Comment: i used this
{=IF(A7="NO","",IF(C7<MIN(OFFSET(INDIRECT(LEFT(D7,2)),MATCH(B7,Table!$B:$B,0)-1,0,1,3)),0,IF(C7>MAX(OFFSET(INDIRECT(LEFT(D7,2)),MATCH(B7,Table!$B:$B,0)-1,0,1,3)),4,INDEX(Table!$F$1:$H$1,MATCH(FALSE,OFFSET(INDIRECT(LEFT(D7,2)),MATCH(B7,Table!$B:$B,0)-1,0,1,3)<C7,0)-1))))}

Comment: its a damn monster.  the indirect points to a different table depending on UOM (ppmv vs mg/m3).  first i find out if it's less than the min or greater than the max and assigned values 0 to min and 4 to max.  if not then i used your formula but replaced the header with 1,2 and 3.  This way depending on my input i get a value from 0 to 4 from which then i can program the rest of the logic.

Thanks again sir, your formula was the missing link.

Comment: Great! I'm glad that you've found the solutioin. :)